# Extracing tf-idf values and features from TfidfVectorizer and making them into pandas Series

Tags: python, sorting, vectorization, tf-idf

I was extracting tf-idf values for each feature name from a text document (in .csv format where each row entry represents a text message (dtype=str)) using TfidfVectorizer with default parameters. This is what I did:

```css
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series

# .csv document has been converted into pandas format
tf = TfidfVectorizer()
X_tf = tf.fit_transform(document)

# get feature names and tf-idf values
feature_names = tf.get_feature_names()
tfidf = tf.idf_
```

I also used the last two lines to extract feature names and tf-idf values. However, I was also asked to (1) sort features by their tf-idf values in both ascending and descending orders, then by alphabetical order (if multiple features' tf-idf values are tied) and (2) make the output into a pandas Series object using feature name as index, such that the output looks like this (this one in descending order):

```css
feature   tf-idf
he         0.031
she        0.047
i          0.068
a          0.084
the        1.527
```

Seems that I can simply achieve this by matching 'feature_names' and 'tfidf' and sort them, but I am not sure if their sequences actually match as 'feature_names' is a list object while 'tfidf' is a numpy array and given that I don't really know what sklearn is doing under the hood.

If I want to compile a sorted Series in descending (and ascending) order with the exact feature name as index (sorted in alphabetical oder), what should I proceed from the last line of my code? If will be really appreciated if someone could enlighten me on this.

Thank you.

Comment: can you provide a small reproducible sample data set (`document`)?

Comment: Yes, I will do that (as 'edit') and add my temporary solution later. It's not pretty but it works.